# задать какую нибудь команду для cmd и командвы exit в одной строке

Tags: windows, bat

надо чтобы например выполнилась архивация файлов с помощью консольной программы Rar.exe и произошел выход из cmd.exe. это надо в ShellExecute написать. я попробывал сделать батник. но он ругается что невозможно открыть файл.

```
Rar.exe a barella_new.rar barella_new; exit
```

Comment: я попробовал сделать так и получилось `Rar.exe a barella_new.rar barella_new & exit`

Comment: [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371)

Comment: Значит вопрос решён?

Comment: @Стас да.......